# PHP remove first zeros on var

Tags: php, ajax, formatting

I want to remove all 0s placed at the beginning of some variable.
I'm sending

```
var = 93
```

by ajax when i echo it's 093

I tried

```
  $exam_sn = ltrim($exam_sn, "0")   ;

  $exam_sn = (float)$exam_sn    ;

  $exam_sn =  preg_replace('~^[0]*([1-9][0-9]*)$~','$1',$exam_sn) ;
```

doesn't work. I also tried

```
$exam_sn = ltrim($exam_sn, "09")    ;
```

the value = 03

Comment: If you're sending `93` from ajax to PHP, it shouldn't happen. Please provide the code you use and make sure that your ajax request is really `93` and not `093` using: `Browser developer tools` -> `network`

Comment: furthermore, `$exam_sn = ltrim($exam_sn, '0');` should work, if not, then its your ajax.

Comment: try to cast the variable as a number in javascript... like -> `data: {'yourkey', +yourvariable}`. The problem here is not really removing the 0, it is rather that that zero shouldn't even be there.

Comment: thank you i tried to restart Xampp and it's working now